# What guarantee does concurrencyLevel argument of ConcurrentHashMap give us?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable, java.util.concurrent

From the Javadocs of ConcurrentHashMap :

> The allowed concurrency among update operations is guided by the
>   optional concurrencyLevel constructor argument (default 16), which is
>   used as a hint for internal sizing.

I do not understand the part that says "which is used as a hint for internal sizing." . What does this mean ? What is the best practice for setting this value and what guarantee does it give us ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the very next sentences in the Javadoc:

> The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated
>    number of concurrent updates without contention. Because placement
>    in hash tables is essentially random, the actual concurrency will
>    vary.  Ideally, you should choose a value to accommodate as many
>    threads as will ever concurrently modify the table. Using a
>    significantly higher value than you need can waste space and time,
>    and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention. But
>    overestimates and underestimates within an order of magnitude do
>    not usually have much noticeable impact. A value of one is
>    appropriate when it is known that only one thread will modify and
>    all others will only read. Also, resizing this or any other kind of
>    hash table is a relatively slow operation, so, when possible, it is
>    a good idea to provide estimates of expected table sizes in
>    constructors.

So in other words, a concurencyLevel of 16 means that the ConcurrentHashMap internally creates 16 separate hashtables in which to store data. Operations that modify data in one hashtable do not require locking the other hashtables, which allows somewhat-concurrent access to the overall Map.

You might want to try reading [the source of ConcurrentHashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap).

Comment: What will be the size of those 16 hashtables ?

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap internally creates 16 separate hashtables in which to store data. - nice info.

Comment: @matt also can you explain the "which is used as a hint for internal sizing." part . What sizing is being referred to here ? is this number of hashtables which is 16 in this case or the size of each of the 16 hashtables ?

Comment: the internal hashtables are not bounded with a maximum size; otherwise your ConcurrentHashMap could only hold `16 * max size` elements. Again, you can take a look at the source of the class itself, the internal table creation part takes place at [line 629](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#629) and the "internal hashtable" is defined as the [Segment class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#242)

Comment: note I changed the link to the source from docjar.com to grepcode.com, the former seems to be using JDK7 source which differs from the ConcurrentHashMap source that ships in JDK6

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency level is around equal how many operations on map can be invoked concurrently without using internal locking mechanism. As maat b is saying that ConcurrentHashMap will have N internal hashtables and thus operations which are working on different hashtables  doesn't require additional locking - otherwise if operations are working on the same internal hashtable then ConcurrenyHashMap uses additional internal locking on them.

Comment: @kodstack ist how many concurrent operatiions or how many concurrent write operations ?

Comment: @Geek it is likely internal issue - basically ConcurrentHashMap guarantees less locking than standard HashMap - other requirements with combinations of input parameters can be validated by performance tests.